# checking memory usage of individual add-ons in Firefox?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, firefox-extensions

I've been getting a lot of memory leaks in the past few months, and I suspect they're caused by one of the add-ons I've installed, but I have no idea which one it is. How do I see how much memory each add-on is using?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [about:addons-memory](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/about-addons-memory/) extension. To use, open about:addons-memory in a new tab.